# Find a subset with distinct values for each column

Tags: algorithm, subset, distinct-values

Given a simple table like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| A       | J       | Q       |
| A       | K       | S       |
| B       | M       | R       |
| B       | N       | S       |
| B       | J       | Q       |
| C       | K       | R       |
| D       | J       | R       |
| D       | J       | Q       |
| E       | L       | Q       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Is it possible to determine whether there is a subset of N rows in this table, such that for each column, all N values are distinct?

For example, with N = 3, the answer would be *yes*

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| A       | J       | Q       |
| B       | N       | S       |
| C       | K       | R       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Is there a simple algorithm to conclude on such a question?

Comment: If you were using SQL, there is the distinct keyword exactly for this purpose.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp - Also if you were using something like Java, things like sets can be used for this purpose. So if you added same entry again it would ignore it.

Comment: @JGFMK no, it is not the same. JGFMK will consider two rows distinct if at least one column is distinct. But here, desired subset must have distinct values in each column independently.

Comment: I don't get this question. How do you come up with B N S first, not B M R. Seems a random selection to me without a pattern.

Comment: @JGFMK If you use `B M R` then you can't choose a third row, because Q and R are used up in column 3, and B is used up in column 1.

Comment: So is there some sort of rule required here to return the maximum number of permutations? Question is very unclear in it's definition to me.

Comment: @JGFMK The problem is to *"determine whether there is a subset of N rows in this table, such that for each column, all N values are distinct"*. The answer for N = 3 is "true". It's a decision problem, not an optimisation problem, and the output doesn't have to be an actual set of three rows; the question just shows those three rows to explain why the answer is "true" for that example.

Comment: Now I get you. Sound like you'd need a stack in there somewhere, to backtrack until you hit a N match. Testing permutations. Each branch omits possibilities. Until stack size hits N. You'd pop stack and try next combo etc.

Comment: You would have sets you'd swap out based on common column 1 perhaps when trying permutations out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple algorithm to conclude on such a question?

The answer to that is strictly "yes"; you can do a [brute-force search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) over all (R choose K) subsets of K rows, where R is the number of rows in the whole table. That algorithm is quite simple, and could be implemented in a few lines in a language like Python.

But I don't think that is the answer you're looking for; I think you want to know if there is a simple algorithm that takes less than exponential time. The answer to that is almost certainly not; the problem is NP-hard, by reduction from the [maximum independent set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Maximum_independent_sets_and_maximum_cliques), so there is no known algorithm which gives correct answers in polynomial time, and it's very likely that no such algorithm is possible.

The reduction is as follows: given a graph, construct a table with one row for each vertex. For each edge in the graph, add one column to the table; in this column write the same letter in the two rows the edge joins, and then write distinct other letters in each of the remaining rows for that column. The resulting table has V rows and E columns, so its size is polynomial in the size of the original graph, and it is constructed in polynomial time.

Then, any set of K rows which have distinct values in each column gives K vertices in the original graph not connected by any edges. This means if you can answer yes/no to whether there is such a set of K rows, in polynomial time, then you can also answer the decision form of the maximum independent set problem in polynomial time. The latter is NP-complete, so therefore your problem is NP-hard.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be simply search (backtracking).

But every tool / library solving [CSP (Constraint satisfaction problem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are explicitly asking for an **algorithm** to solve this:

If I understand the problem correctly (you are using N two times here,the first time for rows and the second time for values, what is a bit confusing), you want to find N rows with ALL DIFFERENT values in the given table.

I would start like this:

1. Create a data structure for a lookup if you already found a value (e.g. a hashmap)
2. Create a data structure to store your result rows which fit the match-condition (all values different)
3. Iterate the input table rows, until you reached your desired subset size or you reached the end of the table
4. Start with the first row
5. While iterating a row, check for each value, if it is in your structure (created in 1.), if yes -> abort, else add the value to the lookup-structure. When all row-values are checked, this row is okay and can be added to your result set.
6. Iterate next row, if existing

But as pointed out in the comment, this algorithm is a greedy one, that will not always find the possible solution

Comment: This is the greedy algorithm; are you sure it correctly solves the problem? Consider the case of two columns and three rows, `(A, 1)`, `(B, 1)`, `(A, 2)`, your algorithm finds a solution of size 1, but a solution of size 2 is possible.

Comment: You are correct, this greedy approche will not find all solutions.